# How should I modify this java code so that it saves all possible paths?

Tags: java

I need java code that chooses the shortest path between two words with each step only changing one letter. I could only implement code that returns with the shortest path.

Comment: Hello I can run your code, but I need to understand the expected behaviour.

Comment: Basically you should edit your question explaining what your code is expected to do, detailing if the current behaviour is correct or not, then explaining clearly what is the improvement you are aiming at.

Comment: That's not answering my request. If I run print(find("hide", "seek", words))  I get: **['hide', 'bide', 'bids', 'beds', 'bees', 'sees', 'seek']** What should be the behaviour you are searching for?

Comment: **hide, hire, mire, mirk, merk, meek, seek** can be found immediately by find("seek", "hide", words)

Comment: @Lorenzo, do you know how to change this code so that the user can ask for a list of all possible UNIQUE paths (no common words) of a certain length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem Restatement

In this question, the find function (remark: the name find does not seem to 
be appropriate. Better use findPath, IMHO) returns a list of words from a 
dictionary of words stored in a string list. A sample dictionary text file 
for the example below can be found in the question.

The findPath function takes three arguments:

- A starting word,
- a target word,
- a dictionary (a list of words).

The find function tries to 'connect' the starting word to the target 
word through a finite 'path' made of different 'steps', i.e. different
words all belonging to the dictionary, but each one differing only by one 
letter from the previous word.

For example,

```
>>> find('hide', 'seek', words)
['hide', 'bide', 'bids', 'beds', 'bees', 'sees', 'seek']
```

This is a 6-step Path made of 7 words.

The current implementation yields only one path amongst all possible shortest 
paths connecting two words, or 'None' if no such path exists. The question is 
then:

**How should I modify it to yield instead a list of all possible paths of a 
certain length, given that no words should be connected only once in 
a valid path?**

## Analysis of the current algorithm

The algorithm will be described by a graph analogy. 
The algorithm builds the 'visited' dictionary as a tree that originates with 
'None', goes to the 'start' word, then branches from the 'start' word to every 
word that can be connected to it.

The algorithm then continues by examining every new single added node ('curr' 
string), in the order it was added to the tree. The algorithm keeps track of 
the words that have been included in the tree with the 'queue' list, so that 
if a word is met again, it will not be considered again.

Once the 'target' word is added to the tree, nothing happens, and this is a 
small pity. One must wait that the 'target' word is examined, to
detect that a path has been found.

When the 'target' word is examined, then the path is returned in a quick
and elegant way by simply browsing back the tree to the root

```
    if curr == target:
        path = []
        while curr:
            path.insert(0, curr)
            curr = visited[curr]
        return path
```

## Current algorithm properties

In the current form and with the sample dictionary, the tree starting with 
'None->lead' has the following branches:

```
bead dead head mead read load lend leud lewd leaf leak leal lean leap lear leas
```

Please note that the current algorithm returns a path that is a function 
of the order in which the words are considered, basically the order of 
the words in the dictionary and the order of the given arguments. Therefore,
as stated in the comment, the current algorithm is able to find one 
*or two* shortest path, since we can invert the order of the arguments, e.g.

```
>>> find("hide", "seek", words))
['hide', 'bide', 'bids', 'beds', 'bees', 'sees', 'seek']
```

but

```
>>> find("seek", "hide", words)
['seek', 'meek', 'merk', 'mirk', 'mire', 'hire', 'hide']
```

so that hide->hire->mire->mirk->merk->meek->seek can be found immediately
as an alternate shortest path.

## Problem analysis

There are two levels of innovation in the question you ask. Firstly, the 
algorithm should cover all possible shortest paths, not only the first path 
being found. Secondly, the algorithm should take an additional number 'n'
and yield back all possible paths of length 'n'.

### Covering all possible shortest paths

The shortest possible path, if it exists, has at least so many
number of steps as letters differing in the two words.

Suppose that you want to connect 'lead' to 'heal'. There are two letters 
difference and a possible shortest path is 'lead->head->heal'. If 'head' was
missing in the dictionary and 'leal' was present, then an alternate shortest
path would be 'lead->leal->heal'. If both 'head' and 'leal' were missing, the
shortest path would be longer than 2.

In general, if you scramble your dictionary (change the order
of the words), you should be able to obtain a different shortest path 
with the same algorithm. But to be sure to obtain all possible paths, 
you should perform an extremely high number of scramble operations 
and that looks to me inefficient.

### Covering all possible paths

Suppose that you want to connect 'lead' to 'heal'. A possible shortest 
path is 'lead->head->heal'.

If you want to consider all possible paths,
you must consider also 'lead->dead->head->heal', 'lead->read->head->heal', 
'lead->dead->read->head->heal', etc., and in some cases some paths that 
have the same content of words as other paths, but with partly permutated order as for 
'lead->read->dead->head->heal'

### Conclusions

It is evident that the current tree structure is unfit to describe all of 
the possible paths, because in the tree structure a single node is
asymmetrically connected on one side with its parent, and on the other
side with all of his children. This asymmetry prevents any possibility 
to consider all possible paths, unless you are ready to duplicate the
tree a very large number of times (but I would not suggest doing so), to cover 
all possibly existing trees.

## Suggestions

1) Divide your problem in two different steps, the first 'covering all
possible shortest paths', the second 'covering all possible paths of length n'.
Attack the easiest problem and solve it considering the second problem, i.e.
do not accept a solution that would be incompatible with the second problem.

2) Reduce the size of your dictionary to a dozen words that you select such to 
offer you the possibility to test quickly your algorithm. e.g.

```
heal
head
leal
real
seal
lead
read
some
more
word
```

allows you to test if you can find or not the two possible shortest paths between 
'lead' and 'heal'.

3) Change of data structure. Leave behind the visited dictionary and its tree,
and use instead another data structure. I would suggest to use a list of lists
covering all possible shortest paths, i.e. in the example above there could 
be one different list for each possible path

```
[lead, leal]
[lead, head]
[lead, read]

[lead, leal, real]
[lead, leal, seal]
[lead, leal, heal] *solution*
[lead, head, read] 
[lead, head, heal] *solution*
```

4) Build a solid testbench : determine by yourself what is the 
expected output for a given problem and work on the code until your test 
succeed. Only then, complexify your test and debug your code again.